# No obtengo al valor exacto de una variable de session en php

Tags: php, javascript, html, phpmyadmin

estoy trabajando en un sistema de curso online (proyecto de clase)
y necesito hacer un formulario donde un usuario agrega las lecciones necesarias para cada curso, pero al momento de darle al botón de aggLeccion me manda datos con la variable de otro registro.
No se si es por que muestro la informacion por medio de un siclo while y agarra el ultimo valor.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aqui los codigos

```html
<?php
 include("conexion.php");
  $usuario2 = $_SESSION['usuario'] ;
   $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM CURSOS WHERE USUARIO = '$usuario2'";
   $result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
  //verificar si existen registros de la busqueda
   if($result2->num_rows > 0){
    while($row = $result2->fetch_assoc()){
    $NOMBRE_C = $row['NOMBRE_C'];
  $DURACION = $row['DURACION'];
  $CATEGORIA = $row['CATEGORIA'];
  $REQUISITOS = $row['REQUISITOS'];
  $DESCRIPCION = $row['DESCRIPCION'];
  $TIPO_CONTENIDO = $row['TIPO_CONTENIDO'];
  $INSTRUCTOR = $row['INSTRUCTOR'];
  $CORREO_INSTRUCTOR = $row['CORREO_INSTRUCTOR'];
  $PRECIO = $row['PRECIO'];
  $NO_LECCIONES = $row['NO_LECCIONES'];
    
  echo"
  <div class='col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 profile_details'>
    <div class='well profile_view'>
        <div class='col-sm-12'>
              <h4 class='brief'><i>".$NOMBRE_C."</i></h4>
              <div class='left col-xs-7'>
                  <h2><strong>Incluye: </strong> ".$DURACION." / ".$NO_LECCIONES."</h2>
                  <p> <strong>Descripcion:".$DESCRIPCION." </strong></p>
                      <ul class='list-unstyled'>
                          <li><i class='fa fa-building'></i>Categoria:".$CATEGORIA." </li>
                          <li><i class='fa fa-phone'></i>Contenido en:".$TIPO_CONTENIDO." </li>
                      </ul>
              </div>

              <div class='right col-xs-5 text-center'>
              <img src='images/img.jpg' alt='' class='img-circle img-responsive'>
              </div>
              </div>


          <div class='col-xs-12 bottom text-center'>             
              <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 emphasis'>
                <a href='aggLecciones.php?msj='>  <button type='button' class='btn btn-success btn-xs'> <i class='fa fa-comments-o'></i> Agg Leciones
                  </button></a>                 
                <a href='aggAlumnos.php?msj='> <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-xs'>
                     <i class='fa fa-user'> </i> Agg Alumnos
                  </button></a>
              </div>
          </div>
    </div>
  </div>";     
}
}

$_SESSION['nombre_c'] = $NOMBRE_C;
$_SESSION['duracion'] = $DURACION;
$_SESSION['categoria'] = $CATEGORIA;

?>
```

```html
    <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                       <div class="x_panel">
              <div class="x_title">
                <h2>Agrega Leciones <small>curso de    <?php echo $_SESSION['nombre_c'] ?>   </small></h2>
                
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="x_content">
                <br />

                <h4>Agrega lecciones a tu curso</h4>
                <p class="font-gray-dark">
                  Con este formulario podras agregar todas las llecciones que tu cursos lleve no tendras un limite pero si deberas llevar un orden al agregarlas.  
                </p>
                <form class="form-horizontal form-label-left"  action="lecciones.php" method="POST">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-3" for="first-name">Tema
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                      <input name="tema" type="text" id="first-name2" required="required" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-3" for="last-name">Descripcion 
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                     
                       <textarea name="des"  maxlength="80"  type="text" id="last-name" name="last-name" required="required" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" name="comentarios" rows="2" cols="30"></textarea>
                    </div>
                  </div>
             

                <h4>Link del contenido</h4>
                <p class="font-gray-dark">
                  Ingresa el link donde esta el contenido de la leccion ya sea un PDF,video, etc.
                </p>
                <div class="col-md-8 center-margin">
                
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label>Link del video</label>
                      <input name="link_video" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter email">
                    </div>
                 
                 <div class="form-group">
                      <label>Link del recurso</label>
                      <input name="linl_recurso" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter email">
                    </div>
                 

                 
                </div>

                <h4>Sobre el curso</h4>
                <p class="font-gray-dark">
                  Agrega los datos que se te piden a continuacion <strong>Son obligatorios</strong>
                </p>
               
                  <div class="form-group form-inline ">
                    <label for="ex3">Id del curso al que pertecene</label>
                    <input name="id_curso" type="text" id="ex3" class="form-control" placeholder=" ">
               
                
                  </div>
               
                
                  <center>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Agregar Leccion</button>
                  </center>
                  <?php

$mensaje = $_GET['msj'];
if ($mensaje == "si"){
    header('Location:aggLecciones.php?msj=') ;
} 
if($mensaje == "no"){
    echo "leccione incorrecta";
}
if ($mensaje == "ya"){
    
    
    echo "La leccion ya esta agregagda, intenta con otra";

}
?>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

en las primeras lineas muestra como llamo la variable de sesión para que me muestre los datos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo utilizaría Jquery en el botón y trabajaría con Ajax.

Pero bueno de acuerdo a tu lógica es cierto.

```
 //asignas la sesión fuera del While por lo que   
 // $NOMBRE_C vale lo que contiene en el último registro
 $_SESSION['nombre_c'] = $NOMBRE_C;
```

Lo que recomiendo es que mejor envies el nombre encriptado desde el primer fuente.

```
aggLecciones.php?ref=base64_encode(".$NOMBRE_C.")&msj=
```

Y al mostrarlo en el segundo fuente que segun veo es el archivo "aggLecciones.php" lo desencriptas.

```
<h2>Agrega Leciones <small>curso de <?php echo base64_decode($_GET['ref']); ?> </small></h2>
```

Y  una vez desencriptado puedes ponerlo en session si vas a seguir usando esa session en tu aplicativo.

```
$_SESSION['nombre_c'] = base64_decode($_GET['ref']);
```

También puedes enviar solo el id de la tabla y luego en aggLecciones.php obtienes el nombre u otros datos que necesites haciendo la consulta con ese valor.

Espero haberte ayudado.
Saludos.

Comment: LO HICE POR MEDIO DE ID MUCHAS GRACIAS @Edwin

Comment: LO HICE POR MEDIO DE ID MUCHAS GRACIAS @Edwin